# Two pairs of items and three times and. How to put the comma?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

I'm just proofreading my thesis a last time and I stumbled upon the following (I'm nonnative english speaker):

> To describe the flow of two fluids with saturations S and T and pressures P and Q, we ...

I'm inclined to use a comma after T to avoid ambiguity. Would this be correct? If I add something to the sentence like

> To describe the flow of to fluids with volumes V and W, saturations S and T, and pressures P and Q, we ...

the comma would be the typical Oxford comma, wouldn't it? However, this is only used if 3 items are listed. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably add *respectively* after *Q* (assuming one fuid has V, S and P and the other W, T, and Q). But this doesn't affect the comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the commas as you suggested. You have misspelled 'two':

> To describe the flow of **to** fluids

Should be

> To describe the flow of **two** fluids.

Comment: Thanks. Would you suggest do add the additional comma or leave it as it is?

Comment: Personally I would add it.